# How to set the reference point of a TikZ drawing to a custom environment e.g. a minipage?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to lower the position a TikZ drawing 1cm down vertically in order to add a blank strip on top of the page. To do that I've added `baseline=1cm` to the parameters of the `\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]` and it did work after recompiling the tex file but after another recompile, the drawing returned back to its previous position!

How to make the drawing stay 1cm below the top of the page in every circumstances or better still, how to set the reference point of that TikZ drawing to a custom environment, say a minipage instead of the whole page, so that I can position the drawing to whereever I want?

Note that I've taken the `\draw` codes from the Internet and don't know much about the  `TikZ`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[left=0cm,right=0cm,top=1cm,bottom=4.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,baseline=1cm]
%\begin{scope}[shift={(0mm,30mm)}]%[]
\draw[gray,fill=lime!20] ([xshift=-2cm]current page.north east) -- ([yshift=-2cm]current page.north east) -- ([yshift=-4cm]current page.north east) -- ([xshift=-4cm]current page.north east);
% \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\pagecolor{gray!10}
    \begin{center}
    {\fontsize{60pt}{55pt}\bf\selectfont The Title Of\\ My Book}
    \end{center}
\addvspace{10pt}
    
\begin{center}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[]{0.5\textwidth}
Some Text...
\end{minipage}
}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Use the special node `current page` (_section 17.13.2 "Referencing the Current Page Node – Absolute Positioning", pgfmanual, p.260_).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `tikzpicture` is drawn on a private coordinate systems and once finished, it's bounding box is computed and it is placed like any other character. If you can change this behaviour, you can use `absolute positioning`, like you do with your code. `current page` node makes reference to the particular page where the `tikzpicture` is drawn with `anchors` like `north west`, `center`, ... In this case, the picture is drawn on these particular positions, usually after two compilations. Therefore, if you want to have a 1cm empty line on top, you can draw the ribbon 1cm below the `current page.north` position. This is what I've done in following code, just adjusting your initial `shifts`.

About the second question, I don't know how to use `absolute positioning` into a `minipage` but if you want to draw something relative to a certain paragraph a possible solution could be to use a `blankest` [`tcolorbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) and draw whatever you want using corresponding `frame` anchors. There is also an example on following code.

Another solution could be to use [`tikzmark`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) references on your text and draw using them.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[left=0cm,right=0cm,top=1cm,bottom=4.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[gray,fill=lime!20] ([shift={(-2cm,-1cm)}]current page.north east) -- ([yshift=-3cm]current page.north east) -- ([yshift=-5cm]current page.north east) -- ([shift={(-4cm,-1cm)}]current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\pagecolor{gray!10}
    \begin{center}
    {\fontsize{60pt}{55pt}\bf\selectfont The Title Of\\ My Book}
    \end{center}
\addvspace{10pt}
    
\begin{center}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[]{0.5\textwidth}
Some Text...
\end{minipage}
}
\end{center}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, blankest, width=.75\linewidth, center, underlay={\draw[lime!40, line width=5mm](frame.north west)--(frame.south east); \fill[lime!50!red] ([shift={(25mm,15mm)}]frame.center) circle(10mm);}]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]